# iPhone - Can you drop pins on mapview if user has no internet connection

Tags: iphone, dictionary

This may be an easy question to answer but I could not find a solution to this doing a search online. Say I have a list of coordinates stored locally that I want to plot (drop pin) on a map view but the user does not have an internet connection, can I still plot the points on the map or does MapKit require an internet connection to achieve this?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even, if you don't have a working Internet connection, you can still drop/add pins to a MKMapView. There isn't anything different. Just note that if your implementation of the annotation does include an online geocoder (to get the name of a street or a location), you have to check for an internet connection.